# Select2 gives error "Cannot read property 'results' of undefined"

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, jquery-select2

I am trying to populate a searchable Select2 form-control with search results from Active Directory.

Here is my select2 function:

```
$("#networkUserSelect").select2({

    ajax: {
        url: '/Account/ADStartsWith',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        processResults: function (data, params) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item)
                /**http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/ **/ {
                var name;
                var id;
                if (typeof (item.displayname) !== "undefined") {
                    name = (item.displayname["0"].replace("  ", " "));
                    id = (item.samaccountname["0"] + "@@email.com");
                    return {
                        text: name,
                        slug: name,
                        id: id
                    }
                }
                else {
                    console.log("display name undefined.");
                }
            })
        };
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, 
    minimumInputLength: 1
});
```

The url is pointing to a C# `WebMethod` that returns the Active Directory data as a `JsonResult`.
Here is the `JsonResult` format as per Postman:

```
"results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "text": "XXX",
            "displayName": "XXX",
            "SAMAccountName": "XXX",
            "givenName": "XXX",
            "sn": "XXX",
            "company": "XXX"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "text": "YYY",
            "displayName": "YYY",
            "SAMAccountName": "YYY",
            "givenName": "YYY",
            "sn": "YYY",
            "company": "YYY"
        }
    ]
```

The JSON is sent back to AJAX successfully. The `processResults` parameters contain the values that are expected.

At some point during the `$.map` portion, it invalidates the results and they become "undefined", and I get the error `Cannot read property 'results' of undefined`.

According to the [Select2 documentation](https://select2.org/data-sources/formats), my JSON is in the correct format.

I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Is `item.displayname` undefined anyhow?

Comment: I am not sure. I can't get breakpoints or console.log commands to execute in that return block. It's almost as if that code isn't being hit at all.

Comment: Have you tried the solution which I've mentioned below?

Comment: The code doesn't seems have issue (after corrections from @RitwickDey) with the data you have given, so something is happening with the data that you have not shared here. You need to get the stack trace of the issue and also it may be a edge case not handled in your code that is causing the issue with the real data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got the problem.
Please give a try. `data` is an object. `data.result` is the array which you're looking for.

**EDIT:** I found 2 more issue - typo in `displayName` & `SAMAccountName`.

`

```
$("#networkUserSelect").select2({

            ajax: {
                url: '/Account/ADStartsWith',
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                processResults: function (data, params) {
                    return
                    {
                        /*
                             Pay attention here. `data.results`
                        */
                        results: $.map(data.results, function (item) 
                            /**http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/ **/ {
                            var name;
                            var id;
                            if (typeof (item.displayName) !== "undefined") {
                                name = (item.displayName["0"].replace("  ", " "));
                                id = (item.SAMAccountName["0"] + "@@email.com");
                                return {
                                    text: name,
                                    slug: name,
                                    id: id
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                console.log("display name undefined.");
                            }
                        })
                    };
                },
            },
            escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, 
            minimumInputLength: 1
        });
```

Comment: This did not work, although it may be due to that code block not being hit as I mentioned in the response to your first comment.

Comment: Oops! I found another issue. It is `displayName`, not 'displayname'. I'm updating the answer in little while

Comment: I updated the answer. Now, please give an anther try. If it does not work, I do know why.! :(

Comment: That also did not solve the issue. Thank you for your time and effort..

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's a problem with your returned json. It should be fully enclosed with { }, like the following:

```
{"results": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "XXX",
        "displayName": "XXX",
        "SAMAccountName": "XXX",
        "givenName": "XXX",
        "sn": "XXX",
        "company": "XXX"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "text": "YYY",
        "displayName": "YYY",
        "SAMAccountName": "YYY",
        "givenName": "YYY",
        "sn": "YYY",
        "company": "YYY"
    }
]}
```

Next, I'm not sure how you want to process the data being returned, but here is a working version of it:

```
$("#networkUserSelect").select2({

    ajax: {
        url: 'results.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        processResults: function (data, params) {
            return { 
                results: data.results.map(item => 
                    ({ 
                        text: item.displayName, 
                        id: item.SAMAccountName + "@email.com",
                        slug: item.displayName
                    })
                )}
        },
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, 
        minimumInputLength: 1
    }
});
```

Once you get this working, maybe you should deal with filtering the data in the backend and passing the `data` param into request body, given that it contains the query filter and pagination attributes.

Answer (score 0):

you have typo it should be `displayName` & `SAMAccountName` and `data` to `data.results` and maybe the last `item.displayName["0"]` to `item.displayName`

```js
$("#networkUserSelect").select2({
  ajax: {
    //url: '/Account/ADStartsWith',
    url: '//api.jsonbin.io/b/5af7d3a97a973f4ce5783c02',
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    processResults: function(data, params) {
      return {
       
        results: $.map(data.results, function(item) {
          var name;
          var id;
          if (typeof(item.displayName) !== "undefined") {
            name = (item.displayName.replace("  ", " "));
            id = (item.SAMAccountName + "@@email.com");
            return {
              text: name,
              slug: name,
              id: id
            };
          }
          else {
            console.log("display name undefined.");
          }
        })
      };
    },
    escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
      return markup;
    },
    minimumInputLength: 1
  }
});
```

```css
.select2-container{width:300px !important}
```

```html
<link href="https://select2.org/assets/7c647dd1b60ff2b17a493d7f00a18e26.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.6-rc.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="networkUserSelect"></select>
```